# How to use different password reset broker in Laravel with mailable class using queues and jobs?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, password-recovery

By using multiple guards I want to attempt reset password using *admin* passwords broker. As in my case there are two guards *web* & *admin*. I want to use *admins* as a broker and use my custom Mailable class **ResetPassword** as an instance to send a reset link email while I am using Queues and Jobs.

Here is my **auth.php** configuration:

```php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],

'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 1,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 1,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

The **ResetPasswordController** logic:

```php
public function sendResetLink(SendResetLinkRequest $request)
    {
        $adminDetails = Admin::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        $email = $request->email;

        if ($adminDetails) {
            $token = Str::random(64);
            DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
                'email' => $email,
                'token' => $token,
                'created_at' => now(),
            ]);

            $link = route('admin.create_new_password', encrypt($token) . '?e=' . base64_encode($email));
            dispatch(new ResetPasswordMailJob($adminDetails, $link));

            session(['true' => 1]);
            return back();
        } else {
            return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'The email is invalid']);
        }
    }
```

The **ResetPasswordMailJob**:

```php
class ResetPasswordMailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $details, $link;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details, $link)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
        $this->link = $link;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Password::broker('admin')->sendResetLink(['email' => $this->details->email], function () {
        //     new ResetPassword($this->details->name, $this->link);
        // });
        Mail::to($this->details->email)->send(new ResetPassword($this->details->name, $this->link));
    }
```

The mailable class **ResetPassword**:

```php
class ResetPassword extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $name, $link;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name, $link)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->link = $link;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Reset Password')->view('emails.reset-password');
    }
```